# Android - Change modifer to static?

Tags: java, android

So I got this bit of code http://pastebin.com/RMh4eHLq from the Android dev blog (modified) but when I try and call it via

`ImageDownloader.download(image, image_main, image_table);`

it tells me to change the download modifer to static but if I do that the ImageDownloader class tells me no portion is accessible. Any ideas?

Comment: The link to the pastebin is now dead. This question is no longer useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
ImageDownloader imgDwn = new ImageDownloader();
imgDwn.download(image, image_main, image_table);
```